# Cannot connect to local datastax cassandra running in docker

Tags: docker, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I executed this docker command to run instance of datastax cassandra:

`docker run -p 9042:9042 -e DS_LICENSE=accept --rm --name my-dse -d datastax/dse-server:6.8.2 -s`

Then this to run instance of the datastax studio:

`docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --link my-dse --name my-studio -p 9091:9091 -d datastax/dse-studio`

When I open the browser at `http://localhost:9091` to create the connection, I get this error:

`All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))`

I checked the cassandra instance running in docker and I can connect using cqlsh:

```
$ docker exec -it my-dse bash -c "cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra"
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 6.8.0 | DSE 6.8.2 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>
```

This is based on the instructions here:
https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/running-dse-microsoft-windows-using-docker

Answer (score 1):

Try querying the IP Address of the container running the my-dse container using the following command from a command prompt:

```
docker inspect my-dse | FINDSTR "IPAddress"
```

You should be able to use that IP address as the Host in the DataStax Studio connection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `127.0.0.1:9092` or `localhost:9042` you either need to specify `my-dse:9042` or `your_machine_ip:9042`.  The main problem is that for every Docker image, the localhost is uniq to that container, and in the Studio container there is no DSE process listening on the port 9042